# javascript function button always show last row

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I have button print if i click that button only print last row in my table. 
that button i use for show data from correct row and print that.
[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS3iC.png)

My query use PDO php.
This table code and javascript function:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($pembelian_polowijo as $pp){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $pp->nomer; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pp->tanggal_pembelian; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pp->nama_penjual; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pp->nama_barang; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pp->berat; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pp->harga_beli; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pp->berat*$pp->harga_beli; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pp->setatus; ?></td>
        <td><button onclick="gg('2');">Print</button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var printer = new Recta('8388907235', '1811')

                function gg() {

                    printer.open().then(function () {
                        printer.align('center')
                            .text('<?php echo $pp->nomer; ?>')
                            .bold(false)
                            .text('<?php echo $pp->tanggal_pembelian; ?>')
                            .bold(false)
                            .text('<?php echo $pp->nama_penjual; ?>')
                            .bold(false)
                            .text('<?php echo $pp->nama_barang; ?>')
                            .bold(false)
                            .text('<?php echo $pp->berat; ?>')
                            .bold(false)
                            .text('<?php echo $pp->harga_beli; ?>')
                            .bold(false)
                            .text('<?php echo $pp->berat*$pp->harga_beli; ?>')
                            .bold(false)
                            .cut()
                            .print()
                    })
                }
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thats not the way php an javascript work together. you define in a php foreach several times the same js function. There just can exist one function with the same gg() name. your foreach overwrite that function with the result of the last $pp

Answer (score 1):

**HTML Code**

```
<td><button onclick="gg( '<?php echo json_encode( $pp ); ?>' );">Print</button>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var printer = new Recta('8388907235', '1811')

                function gg( dataForPrint ) {

                    printer.open().then(function () {
                        printer.align('center')
                            .text( dataForPrint.nomer)
                            .bold(false)
                            .text(dataForPrint.tanggal_pembelian)
                            .bold(false)
                            .text(dataForPrint.nama_penjual)
                            .bold(false)
                            .text( dataForPrint.dataForPri )
                            .bold(false)
                            .text( berat )
                            .bold(false)
                            .text( dataForPrint.harga_beli )
                            .bold(false)
                            .text( Number(dataForPrint.berat) * Number(dataForPrint.harga_beli))
                            .bold(false)
                            .cut()
                            .print()
                    })
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: index.php?page=admins:861 Uncaught ReferenceError: Recta is not defined
    at index.php?page=admins:861

Comment: you have to add Recta lib as well